# C# repeat or close program based on input - Temperature Conversion

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("What is the Temperature in Fahrenheit?")
           string input = Console.ReadLine ();
            double tt = double.Parse (input);
            double cc = (tt-32)*5/9;
            Console.WriteLine(cc + " is the temperature in Celsius");

        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, I need to receive input and close out if I don't.  If their input is (""), the program needs to close, but if they input a number - e.g. 13, I need to have the program loop back to the beginning until I get an input of (""), at which point the program closes.  I'm fairly new to programming, but I've tried everything I can think of to try/figure out, so any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to use loops, as you mentioned; the problem is that you need to repeat some of the lines; declare input outside the loop, and do a while(input!=""), but then you need to repeat some of the lines, in a weird orders; another option is to use while(true) and then add an if (input=="") break; (but many profs in beginning courses frown on breaks :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a `break` statement per se, when used judiciously. But there'd be no need for it here. The prompt and input can be encapsulated into a separate method if someone really doesn't like repeating code (an honorably trait :) ).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Console.WriteLine("What is the Temperature in Fahrenheit?")
string input = Console.ReadLine ();

while (input != "")
{
    double tt = double.Parse (input);
    double cc = (tt-32)*5/9;
    Console.WriteLine(cc + " is the temperature in Celsius");
    Console.WriteLine("What is the Temperature in Fahrenheit?")
    input = Console.ReadLine ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if instead you use a specific character to specify ending the program instead of an empty line, it is relatively easy:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string exit = "";
            while(exit.ToLower != "no") 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What is the Temperature in Fahrenheit?");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                double tt = double.Parse (input);
                double cc = (tt-32)*5/9;
                Console.WriteLine(cc + " is the temperature in Celsius");
                Console.WriteLine("if you want to do another conversion, enter \"yes\" otherwise, enter \"no\"");
                exit = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```